# Mounted function not changing live in Laravel vue

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

Anyone knows why my mounted function not changing the value whenever it changes to a new value? I mean it should be live. The thing is in my `index.vue` I used local storage and set it to `true` and then when the request was a success it will replace and change the value to `false` since I've been using await it will trigger the value to false after the request is done, but the problem is on my main vuejs file when calling `local storage even the value of my localStorage is equal to false, the data still remain to true. It would be great if anybody could figure it out, thank you so much in advance!.

I want to retrieve it

*vuejs file*

```
<div v-if="loadingStatus=='true'" class="overlay-layer bg-dark-o-10">
   <div class="spinner spinner-primary"></div>
</div>


data(){
   loadingStatus: 'true'
}

mounted() {
   this.EmployeeList();
},
methods: {
   EmployeeList(){

        this.loadingStatus = localStorage.getItem('loadingStatus');
    }
}
```

*Vuex file currentUser.js*

```
import axios from "axios";  
const state = {
    employee: [] 
};
const getters = {

    employee(state){
        return state.employee
    }

};
const actions = {
    loadEmployee({commit}){
        return axios.post(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete').then(response => {
            commit('setEmployee', response.data) 
            localStorage.setItem('ListEmployee', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        });
    }
};
const mutations = {
    setEmployee: (state, drivers) => {
        state.employee= drivers;
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

*Index.vue* Root, which trigger all function and call function from vuex file.

```
    async test(){
        localStorage.setItem('loadingStatus', 'true');

        await this.$store.dispatch('currentUser/loadEmployee');
        this.$store.getters['currentUser/employee']; 

        localStorage.setItem('loadingStatus', 'false');
    }
```

Comment: Can you try a triple equals in the v-if?

Comment: @dantheman thanks for your response , I tried but it always the same result do you have any idea ?

Comment: I don't think vue listens for changes in local storage, so you may want to look into using a global state using vuex to store whether it's loading or not.

Comment: @dantheman Thanks for your response Yes, I  already using vuex and I updated my question above with my vuex file, but the result is always the same